# click() for dynamically created button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trying to add click() event for dynamically created button like this

HTML

```
<div></div>
 <button>generate new element</button>
```

Jquery

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("div").append("<input type='button' class='mins' value='button' name='mins[]' />")
});

$.each($('[name^=mins]'), function (i, item) {
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(e) {
 alert("1234");
});
});
```

but unfortunately, it is not working.Please help me to find the problem.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bnq3P/2/)**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be careful that `$("div").append(` will append the button to all the divs of your document.

Comment: And note also that `$.each($('[name^=mins]'),` would be better as `$('[name^=mins]').each(`

Comment: @dystroy, Thank you.I will note your advices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `$.each` loop runs before you add the buttons. So it does nothing.

Change

```
$.each($('[name^=mins]'), function (i, item) {
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(e) {
 alert("1234");
});
});
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[name^=mins]', function(e) {
  alert("1234");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("div").append("<input type='button' class='mins' value='button' name='mins[]' />")
});


$(document).on('click', '.mins', function(e) {
 alert("1234");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bnq3P/5/)

Answer (score 0):

change your code with this code

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("div").append("<input type='button' class='mins' value='button' name='mins[]' />")
});


$(document).on('click', '.mins', function(e) {
 alert("1234");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bnq3P/7/

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input:button[name^=mins]', function (e) {
    alert("1234");
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/bnq3P/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is when you create your button give it a function

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var $input = $("<input>", {
        type: 'button',
        class: 'mins',
        value: 'button',
        name: 'mins[]',
        click: function () {
            alert("1234");
        }
    });
    $("div").append($input)
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bnq3P/13/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't append the input buttons straight to the div. It will append it to all the divs existing in the page. Also, your each loop runs before any input buttons exist so the on event is not bound to any element.

Use:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input.mins', function (e) {  
    alert("1234");  
});
```

Comment: the piece of code here is just sample of what i am trying to do.In real i am adding `<tr>` dynamically to `<table>` and that code was too big.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your javascript code with this code

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("div").append("<input type='button' class='mins' value='button' name='mins[]' />");
$('.mins').off('click');
$('.mins').on('click', function(e) {
 alert("1234");
});
});
```

You can check this working demo here http://jsfiddle.net/bnq3P/14/